# How to easily clean up or refinish cheap top coat on hardwood?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

I recently purchased a home, and it appears that the hardwood floors had a very thin and/or cheap top coat of finish applied to make them shiny with minimal effort.

If I slide **ANYTHING** (even say a kitchen chair with plastic slider feet) across it a thin layer of material comes off and the floor looks less shiny in that area.

I guess this is a two part question:

**1** - Is this a known practice?  Is there a way to check for it before buying a house?

**2** - Is there a workaround for this besides refinishing the entire floor?

Comment: Is it perhaps wax? If so, wax stripper should take it off.

Comment: @DA01-  how can I tell?

Comment: See the answer at the bottom of this page for "If I buy a home with hardwood floors, how can I tell if they have a wax or urethane finish?" http://www.residentialfloors.com/faqs.html

Comment: So it comes up easily with a fingernail BUT it's clear like the urethane.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe cheap/old urethane finish?  Or maybe the last person put a urethane finish over a waxed floor so it did not bond well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be a few different reasons for your situation.  I would lean towards the theory that only one coat of finish, urethane or maybe varnish was applied to a poorly prepared surface.  I'm afraid there is not quick fix to your problem.  I would be looking at stripping and sanding the entire floor, clean away every spec of dust and refinish with at least 3 coats of high grade urethane.  The surface MUST be lightly buff sanded and cleaned between each coat to give you a professional looking finish. It is a lot of work, but the results will be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even if it's not what I want to hear :)  I came to the conclusion last night that they probably just put a quick coat of thin urethane on without prepping, which makes sense.  It's on the todo list now!